# MySQL change query with UNION to query without

Tags: mysql

How will I be able to change this query into one query without using **UNION** or **subqueries**? JOIN is allowed.

The issue is that some products are grouped with a value in the column `group_code`. Meaning that only one should be returned in the query result. I'm using Doctrine querybuilder and I'm unable to use union or subqueries.
I tried to fix this by doing two queries and combine the result with PHP. But when I trie to paginate the result and I would say limit 2, this will return 4 results, because both queries would get 2 results.

#### The query

```
(SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE group_code != '' 
GROUP BY group_code)

UNION ALL

(SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE group_code IS NULL 
GROUP BY id)

LIMIT 0, 2;
```

#### Wanted result:

```
id | title              | group_code
------------------------------------
 1 | t-shirt blue       | t-shirt
 4 | t-shirt with image | NULL
```

#### Table

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#### Data

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `title`, `group_code`)
VALUES
    (1, 't-shirt blue', 't-shirt'),
    (2, 't-shirt green', 't-shirt'),
    (3, 't-shirt orange', 't-shirt'),
    (4, 't-shirt with image', NULL),
    (5, 'sweater', NULL),
    (6, 'jumsuit', NULL);
```

Comment: You should be able the use raw sql in Doctrine like this. `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();->getConnection()->prepare($sql);`

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yes, but in this part of the code I need to use the QueryBuilder. This doesn't support a raw query.

Comment: What's you intention behind this query?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis, I need all records from the product table and the records with the same group_code must be grouped. Pagination should also be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the same result. But the query is a bit risky since you are grouping but not aggregating your results..

```
SELECT *
FROM product
GROUP BY COALESCE(group_code, id)
ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 0,
                 2
```

Comment: What do you mean with the risky part?

Comment: What you get back always depends on the order you inserted it into the table.
Let's say you have a table with names and streets and you run `SELECT name, street from names group by name` If you have the same name twice you'd get back a street but you wouldn't know that there's actually another street for the same name.